# Different localization according to Targets

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have more than 100 targets in my project. This project has 10 different languages. When I upload applications to Apple Store Connect, 10 languages appear on App Store Preview. But I want to do some of appear 4, some of appear 5 and some of appear all languages on App Store Preview. I did packages as you see on picture. I checked target membership of "EnArDeRu" for some targets. These targets support 4 languages what I want but still 10 languages appear on App Store Preview. It should be 4 languages. How can I change languages list on App Store Preview? Could you help me? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: 1. We can't manage it from AppStore Connect. From Xcode you need to set localization language. But as you are targeting multiple targets with only some languages. that's not possible yet because in localization section in the xcode we dont have option for schema based language selection.

Comment: 2. You can give a try with when you upload build for specific target you can remove target membership of that localization file. this way may when you upload build the app appstore connect consider it as only target membershiped languages. but this is not a optimam solution yet you have 100 targets and every time you need to remove and add target membership.

Comment: @Sagarkoyani Firstly, thanks for your response. It doesn't make sense that Apple doesn't support such a thing. I hope it supports something like this in the future. It can be done by deleting as you said, but it would be very difficult to do this way because there are many targets.

Comment: What is the point ? At the end you only will have one app with all languages. You could try making some different list  of tester and each time you make a distribution you chose which list to send the app.

Comment: @PtitXav Firstly, thanks for your response. It's like impossible to choose languages for each app while updating to the Apple Store. I have more than 100 applications on my project. Point is I wonder any scripts or ways to do without delete languages while updating to the Apple Store.

Comment: So, if I understand, you use the same localisation file for each target but with different selected language depending on the target ?

Comment: No, I use 2 different localization string file. One file is localizable 4 languages, other is 10 languages. Some targets selected 4 languages, some targets selected 10 languages. When I upload app which app has 4 languages string to Apple Store, 10 languages appear on App Store Preview.

Comment: Did you checked that the correct localisation file associated to the target it needs to : click on localisation file in navigator and check in inspector tab that is associated to the correct targets.

Comment: Yeah, I checked. The problem is Apple shows language list on App Store Preview from Project Localization. There is no selection by target in the project settings either.